# How to remove rows by values that appear more than once

Tags: r

I have a dataset where I merged two dataframes by the same column. After doing this, I have found that the values of that column `LOC_ID` has more than one `ID` for a single day/week. This is BTO data, and I assume that this is because they updated their habitat metrics and sent off more than one habitat data for the same garden.

I would like the latest to be stored, which I am guessing is the ID value that appears latest in a set of duplicate ID values.

reproducible code:

```
structure(list(year = c(2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
2009), week = c(52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 
52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 
52, 52), POSTCODE = c("IP21 4TR", "IP22 4BD", "IP22 4BD", "IP22 4BE", 
"IP22 4YW", "IP22 5SB", "IP22 5SB", "IP24 2YW", "IP24 3EP", "IP24 3HG", 
"IP24 3NF", "IP25 6QU", "IP25 6QU", "IP25 6TD", "IP25 7DB", "IP25 7EY", 
"IP25 7HG", "IP25 7SX", "IP26 5HH", "IP26 5JD", "IP27 0RQ", "IP27 0RQ", 
"NR10 4EA", "NR10 4EA", "NR10 4PF", "NR11 6JP", "NR11 7QB", "NR11 7QB", 
"NR11 7QG", "NR11 8PA"), OBS_DT = structure(c(14605, 14605, 14605, 
14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 
14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 
14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605
), class = "Date"), LOC_ID = c("LOC633232", "LOC1153084541859", 
"LOC1153084541859", "LOC1300605020", "LOC1049970899816", "LOC628053", 
"LOC628053", "LOC1300611642", "LOC710372", "LOC676185", "LOC696817", 
"LOC1300602161", "LOC1300602161", "LOC1039890913279", "LOC287351", 
"LOC13006219110", "LOC1300605191", "LOC1133275915797", "LOC614479", 
"LOC1300611662", "LOC575712", "LOC575712", "LOC575593", "LOC575593", 
"LOC1300604079", "LOC1300604818", "LOC606431", "LOC606431", "LOC1300612920", 
"LOC1300604135"), HOW_MANY = c(14L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 15L, 15L, 
9L, 13L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 15L, 14L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 11L, 
11L, 16L, 16L, 7L, 3L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 8L), GARDEN_SIZE = c("M", 
"S", "S", "M", "S", "L", "L", "M", "X", "X", "M", "M", "L", "S", 
"L", "X", "M", "L", "M", "L", "M", "S", "L", "L", "L", "M", "L", 
"L", "S", "M"), GARDEN_AGE = c("B", "D", "D", "C", "C", "D", 
"E", "B", "X", "X", "D", "E", "E", "D", "E", "X", "D", "E", "D", 
"A", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "D", "E", "D", "B", "C"), SMALL_DECID_TREES = c("C", 
"C", "C", "B", "A", "D", "D", "D", "X", "X", "C", "D", "E", "C", 
"E", "X", "D", "E", "A", "X", "C", "C", "D", "E", "C", "D", "D", 
"E", "C", "E"), LARGE_DECID_TREES = c("B", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "B", "X", "X", "B", "C", "D", "C", "D", "X", "B", "E", 
"A", "D", "B", "B", "C", "E", "C", "C", "E", "E", "X", "C")), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), groups = structure(list(year = c(2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009), week = c(52, 
52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 
52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52), POSTCODE = c("IP21 4TR", "IP22 4BD", 
"IP22 4BE", "IP22 4YW", "IP22 5SB", "IP24 2YW", "IP24 3EP", "IP24 3HG", 
"IP24 3NF", "IP25 6QU", "IP25 6TD", "IP25 7DB", "IP25 7EY", "IP25 7HG", 
"IP25 7SX", "IP26 5HH", "IP26 5JD", "IP27 0RQ", "NR10 4EA", "NR10 4PF", 
"NR11 6JP", "NR11 7QB", "NR11 7QG", "NR11 8PA"), OBS_DT = structure(c(14605, 
14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 
14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 
14605, 14605, 14605, 14605, 14605), class = "Date"), .rows = structure(list(
    1L, 2:3, 4L, 5L, 6:7, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12:13, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21:22, 23:24, 25L, 26L, 27:28, 29L, 
    30L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = c(NA, 24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What it looks like and the output I want:

```
original:
 year  week POSTCODE OBS_DT     LOC_ID           HOW_MANY GARDEN_SIZE GARDEN_AGE SMALL_DECID_TREES LARGE_DECID_TREES
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <date>     <chr>               <int> <chr>       <chr>      <chr>             <chr>            
 1  2009    52 IP21 4TR 2009-12-27 LOC633232              14 M           B          C                 B                
 2  2009    52 IP22 4BD 2009-12-27 LOC1153084541859        6 S           D          C                 A                
 3  2009    52 IP22 4BD 2009-12-27 LOC1153084541859        6 S           D          C                 A                
 4  2009    52 IP22 4BE 2009-12-27 LOC1300605020           9 M           C          B                 A                
 5  2009    52 IP22 4YW 2009-12-27 LOC1049970899816        3 S           C          A                 B                
 6  2009    52 IP22 5SB 2009-12-27 LOC628053              15 L           D          D                 C                
 7  2009    52 IP22 5SB 2009-12-27 LOC628053              15 L           E          D                 D                
 8  2009    52 IP24 2YW 2009-12-27 LOC1300611642           9 M           B          D                 B                
 9  2009    52 IP24 3EP 2009-12-27 LOC710372              13 X           X          X                 X                
10  2009    52 IP24 3HG 2009-12-27 LOC676185               9 X           X          X                 X             

New Output:

 year  week POSTCODE OBS_DT     LOC_ID           HOW_MANY GARDEN_SIZE GARDEN_AGE SMALL_DECID_TREES LARGE_DECID_TREES
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <date>     <chr>               <int> <chr>       <chr>      <chr>             <chr>            
 1  2009    52 IP21 4TR 2009-12-27 LOC633232              14 M           B          C                 B                         
 2  2009    52 IP22 4BD 2009-12-27 LOC1153084541859        6 S           D          C                 A                
 3  2009    52 IP22 4BE 2009-12-27 LOC1300605020           9 M           C          B                 A                
 4  2009    52 IP22 4YW 2009-12-27 LOC1049970899816        3 S           C          A                 B                
 5  2009    52 IP22 5SB 2009-12-27 LOC628053              15 L           E          D                 D                
 6  2009    52 IP24 2YW 2009-12-27 LOC1300611642           9 M           B          D                 B                
 7  2009    52 IP24 3EP 2009-12-27 LOC710372              13 X           X          X                 X                
 8  2009    52 IP24 3HG 2009-12-27 LOC676185               9 X           X          X                 X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try

```
subset(df,as.logical(ave(LOC_ID, year, week, FUN = Negate(duplicated))))
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this perhaps?

```
library( data.table )
setDT(mydata)[ !duplicated( LOC_ID, by = c("year", "week"), fromlast = TRUE ), ]
```

It looks for duplicates of `LOC_ID` by year-week combination `from the bottom up`, and removes the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` solution:

```
setDT(df)
unique(df, by = "LOC_ID", fromLast = T)
```

Comment: It's best practice to use `TRUE/FALSE` in stead of `T/F`, since the latter ones are symbols that can be redefined.